# Getting erros when I try to install or remove any program

Tags: playonlinux, syslinux, linux-headers, selinux

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
A ler as listas de pacotes... Pronto
A construir árvore de dependências       
A ler a informação de estado... Pronto
A calcular a actualização... Pronto
0 pacotes actualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a remover e 0 não actualizados.
4 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
Após esta operação, serão utilizados 0 B adicionais de espaço em disco.
Deseja continuar? [S/n] s
A instalar python3-dbus (1.2.0-3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dbus.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dbus.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python3-dbus (--configure):
 subprocesso script post-installation instalado retornou erro do status de saída 127
A instalar python3-pycurl (7.43.0-1ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pycurl.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pycurl.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python3-pycurl (--configure):
 subprocesso script post-installation instalado retornou erro do status de saída 127
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de python3-software-properties:
 python3-software-properties depende de python3-pycurl; no entanto:
 O pacote python3-pycurl ainda não está configurado.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python3-software-properties (--configure):
 problemas com dependências - a deixar por configurar
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depende de python3-dbus; no entanto:
 O pacote python3-dbus ainda não está configurado.
 software-properties-common depende de python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.7); no entanto:
 O pacote python3-software-properties ainda não está configurado.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote software-properties-common (--configure):
 problemas com dependências - a deixar por configurar
Foram encontrados erros enquanto processava:
 python3-dbus
 python3-pycurl
 python3-software-properties
 software-properties-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You're missing `py3compile`, which is a part of the `python3-minimal` package. Did you remove Python 3? Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal`.

Comment: I still getting the same error when I try this comand: sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal

Comment: In newer releases of Ubuntu, apt won't work without Python3. You must download the `python3-minimal` package from http://packages.ubuntu.com, and then install using dpkg. After that, try apt again...more packages may or may not be required. Whatever you did to Python3, don't do it again.